# Unable to start free trial for Azure AD P1 or P2 subscription

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am using a free Azure account based on MSDN subscription. I get 50$ monthly credit in this account.

I am trying to start Azure AD P1/P2 free trial but not seeing any option. Is this option disabled for my account ? How can I validate that ? I know this free trial can be started once per account and I have not used it?

I was looking at a video and in that video author is seeing option to start free trial.
[image]

Comment: Click on Licenses, you can see **`Get a free trial`** option like [this](https://i.imgur.com/CvuLNyF.png) in Overview page. Select [Activate](https://i.imgur.com/EzRpgtI.png) option accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

Initially, I have `Azure AD Free` license for my tenant like below:

[image]

To start `Azure AD P1/P2` free trial, you can follow below steps:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Licenses -> Overview -> Get a free trial***

[image]

After selecting *Get a free trial*, click on **`Activate`** as below:

[image]

When I selected *Activate*, **`Azure AD Premium P2`** license activated successfully as below:

[image]